# How do you get node-inspector to work?

Tags: node.js

Install:

```
npm install node-inspector
```

Run app:

```
node --debug-brk c:\users\me\desktop\myapp.js // app stops successfully
```

Run inspector:

```
node-inspector // doesnt work.
C:\Users\me\node_modules\.bin\node-inspector // does work.
```

Open chrome or safari and make sure debugger is on and navigate to localhost:5858. But this releases the app from the breakpoint and it doesn't show up anywhere inside chrome or safari.

[image]

Solution:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go directly to http://​localhost:8080.

Port 5858 is the port that node-inspector uses to communicate with your node process; you don't access it directly.  It speaks V8's raw debugging protocol.

inspector talks to your process via that protocol and serves up a HTTP website on 8080.

Also, npm should have put `C:\Users\me\node_modules\.bin\` in your PATH.  You might need a reboot for that to take effect, after which you should be able to just type `node-inspector` at a command prompt (rather than typing the whole path).

Answer (score 7):

You need to visit `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5850` instead of `http://localhost:5858`.

Answer (score 1):

Visit `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858` to open the node-inspector console.